# Convert JSON Data to JavaScript 2D Array

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON Data:

```
[{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":7},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":2},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":1},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":3},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":7},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":10},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":177},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":13},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":6},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":10},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":9},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":52},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":1},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":2},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":7},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":45},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":27},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":1},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":14},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":9},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":2},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":84},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":6},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":16},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":2},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":4},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":21},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":6},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":0},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":13},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":18},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":10},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":1},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":5},{"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":591}]
```

I want to convert it to 2-D array.
Example :

```
[[Date(1381343400000),7], [Date(1381343400000),2], ........]
```

I tried using `JSON.Parse()` method but it converts it to an array of objects. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure why I can't edit, but the "J" tag is inaccurate and should be removed from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = [
  {"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":7},
  {"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":2},
  {"TxtDate":"\/Date(1381343400000)\/","TxtCount":1}
];


var result = data.map(function (el) {
  return [
    new Date(+el.TxtDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, '$1')), // converts to JavaScript Date
    el.TxtCount 
  ]
})

console.log(result);
```